# Form has stopped submitting, ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I'm having issues with a site I'm developing. I have several detailviews, gridviews and other elements on my site for submitting information.

It has worked flawlessly up until this point, now I'm having the issue that the forms won't submit. The ones that don't work are:

- Insert from my detailsview
- Buttons that submit data
- The save button in edit mode from the gridviews

Nothing happens when they are clicked. However the other things requiring a postback does work, such as cancel, delete and similar functions. Using my a browser debug function I can see that no network attempt is made, so there seems to be some kind of a problem with the client side postback.

I'm guessing there might be an issue using the ASP postback together with jQuery, but I have used it successfully before on this very site. I also tried putting the elements outside of the jquery ui and not including the jquery file entirely, but it didn't seem to help.

Tried in Opera, IE9 and Firefox

Any kind of help or points would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Comment: I guess there must be some validation control, which are preventing postback on button control. Use validation group or set CausesValidation="false" on button to overcome this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It let med to investigate the validation I did. It seems there was another file containing validation code that was causing the issue.

Comment: You are going to need to post some code.  I would recommend focusing on an example where you're having problems with an ASP.net control that you are somehow combining with jQuery (displaying in a jQuery dialog, running some other plugin on the DOM element, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

There was a rangevalidor in another asp file(!) causing the error.
I'm still not sure why, but removing those rangevalidators made things work again which is quite weird.

Update: They were not using a validationgroup which seems to mess things up

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your validators had the same ValidationGroup than your submit controls. But you told that it was in another asp file, so if the files are not "linked", i find it strange...

Only for information : when you have OnClientClick="[...] return false;" on a control, it will not trigger the postback.